# Iterating over ImageCollection or a list of Images

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am unable to iterate over an ImageCollection, therefore I have created a list that contained all images in the ImaheCollection but once I try to iterate over it (by sending each image to a certain function) I get this error:

```
sngl_sen2.reduceRegion is not a function
```

I get this error from the **second** call to `get_List` (the one that sends S2_list[0])

This is the code:

```
var region = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(Map.getBounds(true))])

//Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date("2018-04-01");
var finish = ee.Date("2018-05-01");

//------------------- Data bases ---------------------//
var sen2_for_dates = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate(start, finish)
  .filterBounds(region)
  .map(function(image){
    return image
    .clipToCollection(region)
    .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
    .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('ndvi'))
  })
  .select('ndvi')

//------------------ Creating the feature collection for export --------------//  
function get_List(sngl_sen2){
   var list2 = sngl_sen2.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: region,
    maxPixels: 1e8,
    scale: 10
  });

  // Make a feature without geometry and set the properties to the dictionary of means.
  var feature2 = ee.Feature(null, list2);

  // Wrap the Feature in a FeatureCollection for export.
  var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([feature2]); 
  return featureCollection
}

//Making a list of images so I can iterate over all images.
var S2_list = sen2_for_dates.getInfo()['features']

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: get_List(sen2_for_dates.first()), //works for the first image in the ImageCollection
  fileNamePrefix: 'SEN2_',
  folder: 'AI_data/'+'try',
  selectors: ['ndvi'],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: get_List(S2_list[0]), //Does not work for the first image in the list
  fileNamePrefix: 'SEN2_',
  folder: 'AI_data/'+'try',
  selectors: ['ndvi'],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
```

My final goal is to iterate over the **list** and pass on the images from the list to the `get_List` function (because my original code iterates over more than one list, so I need to index the objects from the different lists using the same indexed)

How can I pass S2_list[0] to the function `get_List` in a manner that will enable it to use it with all the functions that can be carried out in an image (e.g. reduceRegion)?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you want to export Images as CSVs?

Comment: I will later use these CSVs in deep neural networks to estimate NDVI for future dates

Comment: Then why not export them as Images/Tifs? You might have to do some more preparation for the neural net, but it's way easier to export and save

Comment: Aren't these files fairly big to handle? I will need to download all the images from 2017 to 2020 from Sentinel 2 and Sentinel 3

Comment: They are not much bigger than downloading them as CSV, they also do not lack the spatial information.

Comment: Thank you @JonasV, how would you recommend to download them? What part of the code should be changed?

Comment: Hello @JonasV, can you please assist me with the downloading of the TIFFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ee.List() of a Collection using `toList()`. Then make a client-side for loop to export a featureCollection of the pixel data of each image:

```
//Making a list of images so I can iterate over all images.
var S2_list = sen2_for_dates.toList(sen2_for_dates.size());

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var image = ee.Image(S2_list.get(i));
  Export.table.toDrive({
    description: 'exportTast'+i,
    collection: get_List(image), 
    fileNamePrefix: 'SEN2_',
    folder: 'AI_data/'+'try'+i,
    selectors: ['ndvi'],
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
    });
}
```

Possibly, it is best to hard code the number of images in the collection (I set it at 10), though you can also find it using `sen2_for_dates.size().getInfo()`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Kulik!